# Module not found error with Django Channels

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I'm completely new to using channels, but have tried two separate installations, and setups to just get a basic version of channels running and am encountering a small issue. I'm assuming I'm probably just missing a small thing, but I cannot figure it out.

File structure:

```
mysite:
   mysite:
       __init__.py
       asgi.py
       setting.py
       urls.py
       wsgi.py
   testproject:
       __init__.py
       consumers.py
       routing.py
   manage.py
```

The error is at handshake

```
WebSocket HANDSHAKING /ws/livec/ [127.0.0.1:51020]
Exception inside application: 'module' object is not callable
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:  \Users\LTV2g\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 101, in __call__
return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
WebSocket DISCONNECT /ws/livec/ [127.0.0.1:51020]
```

I'll also show the current file structure, as well as the files that I've actually made modifications to.

asgi.py

```
import os

from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from ..testproject import routing

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
  "http": get_asgi_application(),
  "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'daphne',
    'channels',
    'testproject',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

...
ASGI_APPLICATION = "mysite.settings"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
    },
}
```

consumers.py

```
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer


class Calculator(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        self.accept()

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.close()

    def receive(self, text_data):
        pass
        #text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        #expression = text_data_json['expression']
```

routing.py

```
from django.urls import re_path

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/livec/$', consumers.Calculator.as_asgi()),
]
```

Originally, in settings.py having ASGI_APPLICATION set as mysite.asgi.application was resulting in an error so I changed that to mysite.settings and it seemed to work correctly when starting. However, on handshake now this issue occurs, so I feel like that could potentially contribute to it. I've tried on different projects and both encounter this issue.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)